# How to setup Facebook sdk with CodeIgniter to do a Facebook fan Page Tab?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying the following:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('facebook', $this->config->item('fb_config'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $user_id = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $data['user_id'] = $user_id;

        if ($user_id) {

            // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
            // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
            try {

                $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me', 'GET');
                echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
                // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
                // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
                // just ask the user to login again here.
                $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
                echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
                error_log($e->getType());
                error_log($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {

            // No user, print a link for the user to login
            $login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl();
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        }
        die;
    }

}
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Invalid or no certificate authority found, using bundled information
OAuthException
Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application XXXXXXXXX.
```

What can i do to solve this? isn't this the correct way to ask the user to access his profile?
and how to add some scope like you do in the javascript

```
{scope: 'email, user_birthday'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the issue was in the **$this->config->item('fb_config')** array
it should be like this:

```
$config['fb_config'] = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
    'fileUpload' => false, // optional
    'allowSignedRequest' => false, // optional, but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);
```